# Connecting to Kerberrized HDFS , java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name;

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos, cloudera, keytab

I am trying to connect to a Kerberized hdfs cluster , with below code , with same below code i am able to access hbase ofcourse with HBaseConfiguration,

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");

UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);
UserGroupInformation ugi = null;
ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI("me@EXAMPLE>COM","me.keytab");
model = ugi.doAs((PrivilegedExceptionAction<Map<String,Object>>) () -> { 
  testHadoop(hcb.gethDFSConfigBean());
  return null;
});
```

I have been able to successfully access Solr, Impala with same keytab and principal, I am getting this weird Failed to find service name for hdfs.

Please look at below stack trace

```
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name; Host Details : local host is: "Securonix-int3.local/10.0.4.36"; destination host is: "sobd189.securonix.com":8020; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:752)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1988)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1400)
    at com.securonix.application.ui.uiUtil.SnyperUIUtil.lambda$main$4(SnyperUIUtil.java:1226)
    at com.securonix.application.ui.uiUtil.SnyperUIUtil$$Lambda$6/1620890840.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at com.securonix.application.ui.uiUtil.SnyperUIUtil.main(SnyperUIUtil.java:1216)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:643)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.getServerPrincipal(SaslRpcClient.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.createSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:717)
```

After i enabled the debug code for Kerberos i got the below debug log when i call FileSystem.get(); 
Kerberor debug log :

Java config name: null      Java config name: null
    Native config name: /etc/krb5.conf      Native config name: /etc/krb5.conf
    Loaded from native config       Loaded from native config
    16/02/22 15:53:14 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    Java config name: null      Java config name: null
    Native config name: /etc/krb5.conf      Native config name: /etc/krb5.conf
    Loaded from native config       Loaded from native config

> > > KdcAccessibility: reset     >>> KdcAccessibility: reset
> > >       KdcAccessibility: reset     >>> KdcAccessibility: reset
> > >       KeyTabInputStream, readName(): EXAMPLE.COM      >>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): EXAMPLE.COM
> > >       KeyTabInputStream, readName(): securonix        >>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): securonix
> > >       KeyTab: load() entry length: 55; type: 23       >>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 55; type: 23
> > >       KeyTabInputStream, readName(): EXAMPLE.COM      >>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): EXAMPLE.COM
> > >       KeyTabInputStream, readName(): securonix        >>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): securonix
> > >       KeyTab: load() entry length: 71; type: 18       >>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 71; type: 18
> > >           Looking for keys for: securonix@EXAMPLE.COM     Looking for keys for: securonix@EXAMPLE.COM
> > >           Added key: 18version: 1     Added key: 18version: 1
> > >           Added key: 23version: 1     Added key: 23version: 1
> > >           Looking for keys for: securonix@EXAMPLE.COM     Looking for keys for: securonix@EXAMPLE.COM
> > >           Added key: 18version: 1     Added key: 18version: 1
> > >           Added key: 23version: 1     Added key: 23version: 1
> > >           default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 18 16.      default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 18 16.
> > >       KrbAsReq creating message       >>> KrbAsReq creating message
> > >       KrbKdcReq send: kdc=sobd189.securonix.com TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=139       >>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=sobd189.securonix.com TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=139
> > >       KDCCommunication: kdc=sobd189.securonix.com TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=139        >>> KDCCommunication: kdc=sobd189.securonix.com TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=139
> > >       DEBUG: TCPClient reading 639 bytes       >>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 639 bytes
> > >       KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=639     >>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=639
> > >       KdcAccessibility: remove sobd189.securonix.com      >>> KdcAccessibility: remove sobd189.securonix.com
> > >           Looking for keys for: securonix@EXAMPLE.COM     Looking for keys for: securonix@EXAMPLE.COM
> > >           Added key: 18version: 1     Added key: 18version: 1
> > >           Added key: 23version: 1     Added key: 23version: 1
> > >       EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType     >>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
> > >       KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply securonix

Interestingly when i use api of the file system like hdfs.exists()

```
 >>>KinitOptions cache name is /tmp/krb5cc_501
 >> Acquire default native Credentials
 default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 18 16.
 >>> Found no TGT's in LSA
```

Comment: Based on Steve Loughran's bag of tricks (https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html) the key to getting some UGI debugging info is *(1)* env variable `HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG` *(2)* JVM system property `sun.security.krb5.debug`

Comment: I will add my own trick: *(3)* `java.security.debug` set to "gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext" (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html) because the most common Kerberos errors come from your custom JAAS and KRB5 conf files.

Comment: Hi Samson , thanks for your reply and suggestion , so i added the debug statements and found few interesting things , the code gets the filesystem object correctly but when i do call exists() method using the file system object i get the same Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name error

Kerberor debug code :

Comment: Read carefully some chapters of https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/errors.html

Answer (score 5):

I believe the problem is that HDFS expects the Configuration to have a value for dfs.datanode.kerberos.principal, which is the principal of the datanodes, and it is missing in this case.

I had this same problem when I created a Configuration instance from only core-site.xml and forgot to add hdfs-site.xml. As soon as I added hdfs-site.xml it started working, and hdfs-site.xml had:

```
 <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.kerberos.principal</name>
      <value>....</value>
 </property>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Setting this and `dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal` on the Configuration object worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Spark2 and HDP3.1, using Isilon/OneFS as storage instead of HDFS.

The OneFS service management pack doesn't provide configuration for some of the HDFS parameters that are expected by Spark2 (they aren't available at all in Ambari), such as dfs.datanode.kerberos.principal. Without these parameters Spark2 HistoryServer may fail to start and report errors such as "Failed to specify server's principal name".

I added the following properties to OneFS under Custom hdfs-site:

```
dfs.datanode.kerberos.principal=hdfs/_HOST@<MY REALM>
dfs.datanode.keytab.file=/etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.service.keytab
dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal=hdfs/_HOST@<MY REALM>
dfs.namenode.keytab.file=/etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.service.keytab
```

This resolved the initial error. Thereafter I was getting an error of the following form:

```
Server has invalid Kerberos principal: hdfs/<isilon>.my.realm.com@my.realm.com, expecting: hdfs/somewhere.else.entirely@my.realm.com
```

This was related to cross-realm authentication. Resolved by adding the below setting to custom hdfs-site:

```
dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal.pattern=*
```